# iframe target cannot be set to _self in Facebook registration plug-in

Tags: facebook, iframe, registration, target

I'm trying to use the iframe version of the Facebook Registration plug-in on my website, but I'm having problems with the redirection target.

On my site, I have an iframe in the middle of the page; when the user clicks 'register', I want the iframe to navigate to the redirect_uri, leaving the browser on my site. I was under the impression that this could be accomplished by changing the "target" attribute, as described here in the attributes table: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

It seems as though the default, target="_top", should cause the browser window to navigate to the redirect_uri, while setting target="_self" should cause only the iframe to navigate to the redirect_uri. However, nothing I do seems to change this default behavior.

Here's the code for the iframe (app ID and redirect URI redacted)

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
       client_id=MY_APP_ID&
       target=_self&
       redirect_uri=MY_URI&
       fields=name,birthday,gender,email"
       scrolling="auto"
       frameborder="no"
       style="border:none"
       allowTransparency="true"
       width="600"
       height="280">
</iframe>
```

For the target line, I've also tried encoding quotation marks:

```
target=%22_self%22&
```

A few other questions address this issue, but it hasn't been adequately answered.

Here, the bug link is invalid:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6105321/facebook-registration-plugin-forms-target-problem

Here, there are no answers: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7829656/why-doesnt-the-target-attribute-work-on-the-facebook-registration-plugin

And here, one answer suggests that the target attribute is broken when using pre-filled info, which is not documented and doesn't seem to make any sense: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7809805/facebook-registration-plugin-not-redirecting-sending-data-of-logged-in-users

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you get any hint on this issue ??

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set a name for your frame and then referring to the name in the target?

```html
<iframe name = "fbplugin" 
  src = "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
         client_id = MY_APP_ID&
         target = fbplugin&
         redirect_uri = MY_URI&
         fields = name, birthday, gender, email"
  scrolling = "auto"
  frameborder = "no"
  style = "border: none"
  allowTransparency = "true"
  width = "600"
  height = "280">
</iframe>
```

Not sure if that works but could be worth a try.